# Java mouse listener isn't working

Tags: java, listener, clicklistener

I'm studying Java and learning how to use mouse listener. However here is a very simple code which doesn't work.

```
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends GraphicsProgram{

    public void run() {
        isMouseClicked= false;
        addMouseListeners();
        while (true) {
            if (isMouseClicked) {
                println ("OK");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        isMouseClicked= true;
    }

    private boolean isMouseClicked;

}
```

The idea is very simple. "isMouseClicked" is false at the beginning, and once mouse is clicked, it turns to true and print "OK" in the screen. The problem I have is that, if I run in a normal mode, no matter how I click mouse, it will not hit and print "OK". However if I run it in the debug-mode. After I clicked mouse, put a breakpoint on

```
if (isMouseClicked);
```

Then it turns out that it is true and "OK" is printed. Can anyone tell me why is that? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a data race. Use [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: you are right! it seems that the while blocked the access to isMouseClicked. I added "pause" in while and it solved my issue. thank you very much. btw, how can synchronization  be implemented here (I'm really new on this topic)?