# Mouse listener throws no errors but doesn't fire (java)

Tags: java, swing, debugging, awt, mouselistener

I am following code I found on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mouselistener-mousemotionlistener-java/) but the mouse listener isn't firing. I suspect that somehow the implementation of runnable is locking access to my board object, but I'm not sure. I'm in a similar boat to the OP of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464303/java-mouse-listener-isnt-working).

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements MouseListener {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    Game() {
        jf.getContentPane().add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(500,500+30));
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game();
    }
}
```

I suspect but doubt that the mouse listener may not be functioning properly due to it being created in a non-static method, but I doubt that that is the problem. I've tried moving the declaration to the beginning of the constructor, but that didn't help.

Comment: *"My auxiliary classes are on my Github project"* Please don't post code into external sites. For better help sooner post a proper [mre]. Very few people are going through the hassle of understanding your whole project and auxiliary classes. Isolate the problem in a single file (a single class if possible) without customizations such as colors, fonts, images, etc if not related to the issue. To test a `MouseListener` I'd suggest you to 1) Change it to a `MouseAdapter` which already has empty implementations to all the methods, so you don't have those empty methods in your code

Comment: 2) Create a single class with an image / shape that you can click, add the `MouseAdapter` to it, and see if the problem persists, if not, then you could check the differences between both codes (original vs dummy code), if you cannot solve it with your knowledge, then 3) come back again, [edit] your question to include that dummy code that includes everything we need to copy-paste and run it in our computers, without doing any modifications.

Comment: BTW why are you mixing AWT components (Canvas) with Swing components (JFrame). AWT is no longer supported and buggy, switch from Canvas to JPanel which adds more functionality and is a Swing component. `Thread.sleep()` might block the EDT and all custom painting should be done in the `paintComponent()` method (which internally calls `paint()`, not in `paint()` and call `super.paintComponent()` as the first line when you do so

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't know about minimal reproducible examples, I'll change my question to remove it. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events will only register on the component which has focus. Which, in your program is your main panel, the `Game` class. So a quick fix would be just to change:

```
 jf.addMouseListener(this);
```

to

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

But you should add the listener to any component you might want to get the events on, i.e. your main panel, the content pane, and jframe too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with using Canvas instead of JPanel as the superclass. When I switched, the mouse listener started firing.